# Swfit associatedtype compile error

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, associated-types

I was reading the Swift book published by Apple. I have XCode 7.2.1
The code below gives a compile error. I used the code in a playground.

```
protocol Container {
    associatedtype ItemType
    mutating func append(item: ItemType)
    var count: Int { get }
    subscript(i: Int) -> ItemType { get }
}
```

You can see the code [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html) on the second half of the page.

Here's the error:
[image]

I'm not sure if this is the right change to the code; but when I change the 1st line in the protocol from

```
associatedtype ItemType
```

to

```
typealias ItemType
```

the error goes away.

Comment: "the error goes away" But it would be better to upgrade to Xcode 7.3. It has Swift 2.2, and Swift 3 is just around the corner. You are behind, and you will have more and more trouble dealing with modern code (and when Swift 3 comes, you will be totally mystified).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 7.2.1 is still on Swift 2.1.

With Xcode 7.3, the current version of Xcode, Xcode started using Swift version 2.2.

Between Swift version 2.1 and 2.2, use of `typealias` within protocols was changed to the new `associatedType` keyword.

So with that said, the documentation you are looking at in the Swift book published by Apple has been updated to the Swift 2.2 syntax, however you're using a version of Xcode which has not been updated to Swift 2.2 syntax yet.

So, as you correctly learned, by using `typealias` in place of `associatedType` in your protocols, it will compile correctly in Xcode 7.2.1.

But it should probably be recommended that if possible, you go ahead and upgrade to Xcode 7.3 and use Swift 2.2.  If you do this, the updated Swift 2.2 examples from Apple's Swift book will work perfectly fine in your Xcode.

Answer (score -1):

Yes that keyword did change in Swift version 2.2. https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0011-replace-typealias-associated.md